# Windows Toast Notification callback not being invoked

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, toast

I managed to send Toast messages but once clicked, the callback is not invoked. This is the [toast-tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop-cpp-wrl) that was used.

The messages should be sent through classic Win32 and in order to do this, a shortcut needs to be created which contains the AUMID and the CLSID. This is explained in Step 5 of the tutorial, where for MSIX and WiX these id's are put in their config files. There isn't an explanation how to generate the shortcut in Win32, but can be found in another [aumid-tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/enable-desktop-toast-with-appusermodelid).

After following the steps provided, sending the toast works fine, but clicking it does not invoke the callback for handling the feedback.
One thing that stands out, is that the installShortcut function uses only the AUMID in the creation of the shortcut, the CLSID is only used when registering the COM Server, where the configuration for MSIX and WIX shortcuts use both.

It seems as there is the link missing that windows needs to route the feedback back into the app.

Toasts use the "ToastGeneric" binding.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Have you run the [desktop-toasts](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts) sample linked in Resources? And I have run the [DesktopToasts](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/DesktopToasts) sample successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just on the name alone it seems to me like you need to set the [`PKEY_AppUserModel_ToastActivatorCLSID`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-appusermodel-toastactivatorclsid) property on the .lnk and not just the AUMID.

MSDN says:

> Used to CoCreate an INotificationActivationCallback interface to notify about toast activations.

[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/win32_tile_badge_notif/respond-to-toast-activations#creating-a-shortcut) is marked as pre-release but does have a different InstallShortcut function that sets this property.

Comment: Thanks for this, this is exactly what I needed. Strange that it is hidden in some unreleased tutorial when it is such a crucial step in creating the shortcut in win32

Answer (score 0):

I have run the [desktop-toasts](https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/desktop-toasts) sample successfully. As the code comment comments,

> For the app to be activated from Action Center, it needs to provide a
> COM server to be called when the notification is activated.  The CLSID
> of the object needs to be registered with the OS via its shortcut so
> that it knows who to call later. **The WiX installer adds that to the
> shortcut. Be sure to install the app via the WiX installer once before
> debugging!**

If running the package project directly, It also works. The following picture shows What happens when I installed **DesktopToastsCppWrlApp.msi** generated by Wix Toolset.
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I knew this example already but we want to use pure win32 and not the tools mentioned so unfortunately this way of creating the shortcut is not an option.

Comment: [DesktopToasts](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/27ffb0811ca761741502feaefdb591aebf592193/Samples/DesktopToasts/CPP/DesktopToastsSample.cpp#L22) sample