# Win32 notification area access: getting user clicks after balloon timeout

Tags: winapi

The notification balloon's message stays in the Windows 11 notification area (the one that opens when clicking the date/time) after the balloon has timed out. Is there a way to get notifications when the user clicks there?

I'm currently using the [SDK example for `Shell_NotifyIcon()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/samples-notificationicon). Getting the event for an immediate click on the primary desktop balloon shown outside of that area works fine.

Comment: I'd guess you'd need to use a newer API (maybe the [Toast Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-other-apps) API?) for that. Legacy shell notifications are just displayed in there as a kind of "notification history", there's no way to receive click notifications once the timeout has passed.

Comment: [There are two DesktopToasts samples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70582103/windows-toast-notification-callback-not-being-invoked/70589863#comment124783117_70582103) which you may have a look.